# How to Insert label value into MS Access Database

Tags: c#

I tried inserting label value into MS Access with the codes below but I keep getting "syntax error in Insert Statement". Please could anybody help. Thanks

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Born To Win";
        label4.Text = "£10";

        connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source =C:\Users\Kunle\Documents\Winners App\winnersBookShop.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        try
        {

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transaction([Title], [Price]) VALUES('" + label2.Text + "','" + label4.Text + "')";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Successfully");


        }

        catch (Exception r)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccesssful" + r);

        }
```

Comment: Transaction is a reserved word. Need square brackets around it. Said that, please learn how to use a parameterized query. Concatenating strings makes this code dangerous and source of innumerable bugs

Comment: What value type is Price? You're just passing it a string at present.

Comment: Thanks a million. It's been sorted. It was the reserved word "Transaction".